# Avro schema evolution throwing EOFException while deserializing

Tags: java, scala, sbt, avro

I have a no-sql db where I am storing serialized avro objects. I use [sbt-avro](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-avro) plugin to generate java classes specifically `addSbtPlugin("com.cavorite" % "sbt-avro-1-8" % "1.1.5")`. Now I want to add new fields to the schema and also want backward compatibility with the data already present. But deserialization of old data using new schema is throwing `java.io.EOFException`

Old Schema:

```
{
  "name": "DNode",
  "namespace": "my.model",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "prev", "type": ["null", "string"]},
    {"name": "next", "type": ["null", "string"]}
  ]
}
```

New Schema:

```
{
  "name": "DNode",
  "namespace": "my.model",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "prev", "type": ["null", "string"]},
    {"name": "next", "type": ["null", "string"]},
    {"name": "size", "type": ["null", "long"], "default": null}
  ]
}
```

Deserialization code

```
  def deserialize(bytes: Array[Byte]) = {
    val reader = new SpecificDatumReader[DNode](classOf[DNode])
    val decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(bytes, null)
    reader.read(null, decoder)
  }
```

Throws

```
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.ensureBounds(BinaryDecoder.java:473)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readInt(BinaryDecoder.java:128)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readIndex(BinaryDecoder.java:423)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:290)
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:267)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:116)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:222)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:175)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:145)
...
```

Comment: we are getting the same error, any update on this?